# How does Undead warlock 'Grave Touched' interact with aoe

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, area-of-effect, archetype

I am confused about how the undead warlock's Grave Touched ability interacts with spells like *Fireball*. The text for Grave Touched reads as follows

> In addition, **once during each of your turns**, when you hit **a**
> creature with an attack and roll damage against the creature, you can
> replace the damage type with necrotic damage. While you are using your
> Form of Dread, you can roll one additional damage die when determining
> the necrotic damage the target takes.

Emphasis on the "a" meaning it affects a singular creature. Does that mean when you cast *Fireball* and hit several creatures then would only one creature take necrotic damage while the rest take fire damage? Finally how would the extra damage die work with an aoe spell like *Fire ball*? Would every creature hit by it take the extra 1d6 damage or would just one creature take it?

Comment: Forgot about that tag. Updated thanks!

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as it has effectively been asked before, just not about this specific feature. The linked question should answer this one clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Area of Effect spells aren't attacks - anything that cares about "an attack" will only interact with things that have you make an attack roll to hit a target.

> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re
> doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you’re
> making an attack roll, you’re making an attack.

(phb 194)

Comment: added the best relevant quote I could find

Comment: I should have also asked about spells like scorching ray that require attack rolls and have multiple beams. Does only one of those beams turn into necrotic damage or do all of them do? (The extra damage die only applies to one of the beams I understand, I am just asking about damage type for the other beams).

Comment: You'll only get the changed damage type for one beam, you get to choose after you hit but before you roll damage.